# How to query the "Props" table from Flexible Search?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Inside my code I have the primary keys of some page components in Hybris and I have to find all their attributes (properties like title, content etc.)

I can query the "Props" table using an SQL query, but I'm not sure how to find the equivalent in Flexible Search, since querying the database directly is not recommended.

Is there any other simpler way to retrieve all the properties of a component having just the primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is retrieve the required component using it's primary key. Example:

```
select {pk} from {SimpleCMSComponent} where {pk} ='8796093056060'
```

Usually flexible searches are used in DAO classes(Platform example: **DefaultProductDao**).

When this flexible search is run by the flexible search service you get a ComponentModel. Please see below a groovy script I just created in order to exemplify how to print the ID of a Component retrieved based on its PK(In the same way by using getters you can get the **title**, **content**, etc.. ):

```
import de.hybris.platform.cms2.model.contents.components.SimpleCMSComponentModel;


def flexibleSearchService = spring.getBean("flexibleSearchService");

SimpleCMSComponentModel simpleCmsComponent = flexibleSearchService.search("select {pk} from {SimpleCMSComponent} where {pk} ='8796093056060'").getResult().get(0);
println(simpleCmsComponent.getUid())
```

I believe though that the best practice in case of CMS Components is to use their IDs instead of PK.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I can map using the `PK` to a `SimpleCMSComponentModel` object, but it won't help me, since there is no method to get the properties of a `SimpleCMSComponentModel` object. I'm not interested in the value of the attributes, but their keys. I want to find out for example what attributes the element with a given `PK` has (one element can have `title`, `description` and other elements can have only `content`). I'm interested to retrieve these keys, not their values.

Comment: What it means then is that you need the actual type of the component: For this you can replace the "println(simpleCmsComponent.getUid())" with "println(simpleCmsComponent.getClass())". In order to get the keys(attributes)  i believe the only way is using reflection for the class object resulted previously ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746158/how-to-read-object-attribute-dynamically-in-java

Comment: Using reflection I managed to get the attributes. However, I still have to parse the keys of the superclasses as well until `SimpleCMSComponentModel`. Not very optimal, but looks like the only way. Thanks for your help!